# Google analytics-style custom report builder UI

Tags: user-interface, reporting, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm looking for a reporting engine/UI that can be integrated into a product, which has a UI along the lines of Google Analytics' Custom Reports builder. Is anyone aware of such a thing?

The data is in our case is not page views/visitors/etc, but is similar in nature, in that there are limited entities or types of data, but each entity has many attributes/columns and many different ways of aggregating data (or in GA-style speak, metrics and dimensions).

The analytics-style UI is very intuitive and allows many reports to be created in powerful ways, without having to know SQL.

I have preference for a web-based tool (seeing that it is 2010 and this is a web app -- I mention only because it seems the vast majority of reporting tools still have only a non-web-based creation tool).

---

Example UI screenshot:

[alt text http://gregmaclellan.com/analytics-custom-search.png](http://gregmaclellan.com/analytics-custom-search.png)

- you can drag metrics from the sidebar into the dotted rectangles - these become the columns (and determine the underlying entities used for the data)
- You can select dimensions to add grouping

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com), a web-based reporting solution that is easy to install and allows you to create reports within minutes.

myDBR also features a report wizard and query builder that allows you to build reports without extensive SQL knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) is similar to Google Analytics but its more powerful as it also gives the administrators insight  into resource consumption.

Answer (score 0):

While not quite as elegant, Report Builder 1.0 coupled with a model of the datast can possibly provide a solution. The table/data structure can be defined in the model to provide drag and drop placement of columns into a grid (one example - it does charts also), and you could define the Dimensions via the use of Filters. Best part is it is free and comes with MS SQL. [More info on Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159862.aspx)